# Issue loading a model of Spanish data

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

I'm trying to load a model of that contains spanish words using gensim-1.0 in python3.5, but when I do `gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(mymodel)` the CLI says this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prueba.py", line 30, in <module>
    model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('./data/WikiModelEsp/wiki.size.800.window.5.mincount.50.new.model', binary=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 192, in load_word2vec_format
    header = utils.to_unicode(fin.readline(), encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 231, in any2unicode
    return unicode(text, encoding, errors=errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I try to call load function with `encoding='latin1'` and `binary=True` but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try only with load function? Like this one:
model = KeyedVectors.load(path_model)